# How to Auto-Start and Stop a VM with Remote Connect/Disconnect?

Tags: virtual-machines, windows-10

Is there a way to simply connect to VM without going to server website to start it but instead to instantly start it by maybe when remote connection is requested, stopping the server is easy enough by pressing shutdown button. The goal is to decrease server cost as I use it for couple of hours a day, so it's not smart to let it run for whole day. Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Looked into Wake On LAN?